# How to resolve 'cannot GET' error on react routes when using ExpressJS to serve react build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have the following folder structure for a React client and ExpressJS server setup. I'm trying to serve the react build files from the Express server. I also have defined some route handlers for API from the express server

```
server                    /* NodeJS server folder
  -node_modules
  -app.js
  -package.json
client                    /* React client folder  
  -build
  -node_modules
  -src
     -components
     -App.js
     -index.js
  -package.json
```

My express (app.js) has the following code

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});
...
...
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    res.json(data);
});
```

Here I'm able to see the home page of my React application but all the routes throws `Cannot GET /reactroute`. I'm also able to access the `/data` as defined by `app.get handler`

**Referring some other answers I changed my code in the express server a**s

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});
...
...
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    res.json(data);
});
```

At this time I'm able to access the routes from the react but the `/data` is not giving the JSON (API) instead it is acting like an another route.
What changes need to be done to get both react routes from the build folder and the route handlers defined in the express.

Comment: You have to place `get /data` before `get *`. If you place `get *` first, it also includes /data.

Comment: Can you post your full `server/app.js`  file?

Comment: @Mani I think your solution works here thanks. If you can post it as an answer by reasoning it will be helpful for other

Comment: Okay, I will answer with explanation

Comment: @LucaPizzini thanks for your response. I do not have much in the app.js as I'm doing some learning and testing ..

Comment: @LalasM I answered this question.:) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to place `get /data` before `get *`.
Like this:

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    res.json(data);
});
...
...
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

If you place `get *` first, it also includes /data. Where `*` considers all routes which are not mentioned before it.